# ¿Cómo puedo anidar una consulta .distinct() con un .find() en Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongoose

Necesito usar el array que me retorna el distinct para usar cada dato con la funcion find, exactamente para obtener cada contrato y con cada uno hacer la consulta find y filtrarlo. Uso Node.js y Mongoose

```
const hasta = moment(new Date()).add(30, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
const desde = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

//La función que me retorna la colección con los contratos

```
Dispositivos.distinct("contrato", function (err, result) {
  for (var x in result){
    console.log(result[x]);
  }
});
```

//Función que me sirve para filtrar los documentos de la colección inventario_dispositivos

```
 Dispositivos.find({
      contratos : "contrato que necesito del array de distintc",
      fecha_proximo_mantenimiento: { 
        $exists: true 
      }
    },
      {
        _id: 0,
        'informacion_equipo.ususario_red': 1,
        fecha_proximo_mantenimiento: 1
      })
      .where('fecha_proximo_mantenimiento')
      .gte(desde)
      .lte(hasta)
      .exec(function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        } else {
          for (var x in result) {
            console.log('numero de documento: ', x, result[x])
          }
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que hice fue con un ciclo for recorrer el array de objetos y programé toda la función con crontab para que me ejecute constantemente

```
const hasta = moment(new Date()).add(30, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
const desde = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

//Se ejecuta cada minuto
cron.schedule('* * * * *', () => {

  const Dispositivo = Dispositivos.distinct("contrato").then(function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      Dispositivos.find(
        {
          contrato: data[i],
          fecha_proximo_mantenimiento: {
            $exists: true,
            $gte: desde,
            $lte: hasta
          }
        },
        {
          _id: 0,
          'informacion_equipo.ususario_red': 1,
          fecha_proximo_mantenimiento: 1
        }
      ).then((devices) => {
        if (devices.length === 0) {
          //Se saltan los vacios
        } else {
          //Envio de correos
          console.log(devices)
        }
      }).catch(err => {
        alert(err)
        return devices;
      })
    }

  });
  Dispositivo.then(null, function showNullError(err) {
    alert('Hubo un error inesperado al obtener los contratos', err)
  });
});
```